# unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hardware

I am trying to connect to a CCD camera that communicates through a PCI card.

When the PCI card is sitting directly in the PC there is no problems, but when the PCI card is connected to the PC through a fiber extender, I get the following error:

```
[ 1402.460924] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000038
[ 1402.460981] IP: [<ffffffffa04f76f1>] AndorDisableInterrupts+0x21/0x40 [andordrvlx]
[ 1402.461030] PGD 3e7eec067 PUD 3ea331067 PMD 0 
[ 1402.461063] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[ 1402.461089] CPU 0 
[ 1402.461101] Modules linked in: andordrvlx(O) ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables rfcomm bnep bluetooth parport_pc ppdev nfsd nfs lockd fscache auth_rpcgss binfmt_misc nfs_acl sunrpc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek tpm_infineon shpchp coretemp snd_hda_intel kvm ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel cryptd aes_x86_64 snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_timer snd_seq_device lpc_ich hp_wmi sparse_keymap snd soundcore snd_page_alloc microcode tpm_tis psmouse serio_raw wmi i915 drm_kms_helper mac_hid drm mei i2c_algo_bit video lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid ahci libahci e1000e
[ 1402.461564] 
[ 1402.461570] Pid: 2295, comm: image Tainted: G        W  O 3.5.0-44-generic #67~precise1-Ubuntu Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq Elite 8300 CMT/3396
[ 1402.461642] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa04f76f1>]  [<ffffffffa04f76f1>] AndorDisableInterrupts+0x21/0x40 [andordrvlx]
[ 1402.461699] RSP: 0018:ffff8803e7de1e98  EFLAGS: 00010282
[ 1402.461729] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffffffffa04fc428
[ 1402.461767] RDX: ffffffffa04fc3c8 RSI: ffffffffa04fc428 RDI: 0000000000000000
[ 1402.461805] RBP: ffff8803e7de1e98 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1402.461843] R10: ffff8803e7e99510 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
[ 1402.461881] R13: ffff8803e55923c0 R14: ffff88040285d2c8 R15: ffff88040285d2c8
[ 1402.461920] FS:  00007fe7d9899740(0000) GS:ffff88041ea00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1402.461963] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1402.461994] CR2: 0000000000000038 CR3: 00000003e7d1b000 CR4: 00000000001407f0
[ 1402.462032] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[ 1402.462070] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[ 1402.462109] Process image (pid: 2295, threadinfo ffff8803e7de0000, task ffff8804041b1700)
[ 1402.462152] Stack:
[ 1402.462165]  ffff8803e7de1eb8 ffffffffa04f8ac4 ffff8803e7e99500 0000000000000008
[ 1402.462213]  ffff8803e7de1f08 ffffffff81189e7e ffff8803e7e99510 ffff880404270160
[ 1402.462261]  000000000000a002 ffff8803e7e99500 ffff8803eecc3440 0000000000000000
[ 1402.462309] Call Trace:
[ 1402.462329]  [<ffffffffa04f8ac4>] andor_release+0x54/0x90 [andordrvlx]
[ 1402.462370]  [<ffffffff81189e7e>] __fput+0xbe/0x240
[ 1402.462400]  [<ffffffff8118a025>] fput+0x25/0x30
[ 1402.462428]  [<ffffffff81186ca6>] filp_close+0x66/0x90
[ 1402.462458]  [<ffffffff81186d6e>] sys_close+0x9e/0x110
[ 1402.462491]  [<ffffffff816a7729>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 1402.462524] Code: c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 63 d7 48 69 d2 90 03 00 00 48 8b 82 c8 c3 4f a0 48 81 c2 c8 c3 4f a0 <8b> 40 38 48 8b 12 25 ff ef 00 ff 89 42 38 e8 ec fe ff ff 31 c0 
[ 1402.462785] RIP  [<ffffffffa04f76f1>] AndorDisableInterrupts+0x21/0x40 [andordrvlx]
[ 1402.462831]  RSP <ffff8803e7de1e98>
[ 1402.462851] CR2: 0000000000000038
[ 1402.556994] ---[ end trace 50d359ca26ea68e0 ]---
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you confirm that the extender works with other PCI cards?

Comment: Yes, There is also a ethernet PCI card connected, and this works fine.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the location of the working card with the non-working card?

Comment: Well, the ethernet card is actually an PCIe card, so that is not possible. The fiber extender has two PCI slots and two PCIe slots.

Comment: Can you confirm that the extender works with other PCI cards? Not PCIe and in the same location as the card you are having the trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

This surly looks like a BUG with an out-of-tree module: andordrvlx. The above type of Oops means that we've dereferenced an invalid pointer which resulted in the kernel Oops.

[ 1402.460981] IP: [] AndorDisableInterrupts+0x21/0x40 [andordrvlx]

You should be submitting a bug report as per (Debugging Kernel OOPS)[[https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelOops]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelOops%5d)